# How to generate a sequence number using JPA and MySQL?

Tags: mysql, jpa

I'm using JPA and mysql and want to generate a sequence number. All examples and references i find point to using @TableGenerator, and this looks like it would suit my needs.

However in all examples i find it is used with the context of an @Entity for key generation in the entity.

But i don't want the sequence number for any @Entity. I just want to get an increasing number for use in multiple other processes.  Is it possible to use @TableGenerator outside the context of an @Entity? Or do i just have to do it all myself in some old fashioned way?

Thanks

Comment: Either you can implemented it yourself (it is simple) or easier define an Entity with just id. You will use its id after persisting as your generated value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL provides this capability via the [`UUID_SHORT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid-short) function.

To see it in action:

```
SELECT UUID_SHORT(); # then repeat.
```

The function provides a monotonic counter that returns a 64-bit unsigned integer that increments by 1 each time it is called.  It can generate 16M values per second, for every second the server has been running, without duplicates.

When the server restarts, the counter is reinitialized to a higher value than previously seen.  There are caveats, but they are documented and easily understood.

Each of up to 256 different MySQL servers will generate their own unique sequences, as long as the LSB of eachserver's server id is unique.